# Suggest how to convert wirefy css framework to bootstrap css framework

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-frameworks, wireframe

In our project we are using WIREFRAME( Base 16 columns) css framework, we want to change the framework to Bootstrap, IS there any easy way to change, or do we need to re write entire css again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to convert to Bootstrap unless there are particular styles that Bootstrap offers that Wirefy doesn't. Wirefy is meant to work as a foundation that you can build your entire app on. This means that you can include additional frameworks or stylized classes on top of it without having to convert.

If you still feel you need to convert then it really depends on the types of classes you've included into your wireframe and how they align with that of Bootstrap.